# Why I obtain this error trying to define a query with parameter in this old PHP application? (Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in...)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pretty new in PHP and I have the following problem trying to define a simple query with parameter on an old PHP application. I have done in this way (mimic the other working query in this application that was made by someone else):

```
$result_facility_list = $db->prepare("select name from pm_facility where lang = :id_lang");
$result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", 2);
```

Then

The problem is that when it try to perform the second line that bind the integer value 2 to the **:id_lang** parameter I obtain this error message:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeTrivius-Panda\templates\default\models\booking.php on line 534
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0326  165272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   8.2043  835656  include( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\BeTrivius-Panda\templates\default\models\booking.php' )   ..\index.php:146
```

What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: $result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", 2); change this line to $id =2;$result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", $id);

Comment: parameters should be passed as variables not direct values

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php since you seem new to MySQL/PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
$result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", 2);
```

to

```
$id=2;
$result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", $id);
```

because you need to pass values to bindparam as variables

Comment: you didn't pass $id

Comment: @vSugumar ok, it seems work. Another doubt. The defined query retrieve a list of rows (containing the single "name" column). How can I obtain an array of these values after that I have perform the "$result_hotel_file->execute();" statment?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind the int `2` to `:id_lang` without it being a variable you can use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
$result_hotel_file->bindValue(":id_lang", 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

if you want to use [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (as the name somewhat implies) you will have to use a variable:

```
$yourIdVar = 2;
$result_hotel_file->bindParam(":id_lang", $yourIdVar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```